# Python - How can I get the largest decimal of two decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have two values of type decimal i.e `<class 'decimal.Decimal'> and <class 'decimal.Decimal'>`
and the numbers are

```
print(option.principal.amount, 'and', max_monthly_amount.amount)
```

Outputs

```
500000.00 and 500000
```

Getting max of the two values like this

```
option.principal.amount.max(max_monthly_amount.amount)
```

Returns

```
'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'max_term'
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the numbers? With `<` and `>` operators?

Comment: I have tried converting both numbers to float and still got the same error
'float' object has no attribute 'max_term'

Comment: Please share the _full_ error traceback. Also see how to write a [mre]

Comment: What version of Python do you use? This is not reproducible with Python 3.6 - 3.10. Using `Decimal.max` works just as expected.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with the [**`max`** function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) in the standard library:

```py
max(option.principal.amount, max_monthly_amount.amount))
```

Answer (score -1):

you should convert both of them to float and then use max function this way :

```
num1 = float(option.principal.amount)
num2 = float(max_monthly_amount.amount)
print(max(num1, num2))
```